# WPF: TreeView - conditional placement of button to expand subitems

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatemplate, treeviewitem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I would like to build a TreeView with the following features:

1. The first level should have the expander-button not on the left but on the right side
2. All sublevels should have the expander-button on the left - just like the default TreeViewItem
3. Expanding/Collapsing should be animated just like the expander-control

I was messing around with DataTemplate and HierarchicalDataTemplate, but the Expander-Button does not seem to be part of the Template, its always added to the Template and always on the left side.
How can I place the Expander-Button depending on the item-level?

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize the [TreeViewItem ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by changing the ToggleButton column. Then you can just change the controltemplate using a DataTrigger inside a style.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
  <!-- snip -->
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Expander"
              Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ClickMode="Press"/>
      <Border Name="Bd"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                  ContentSource="Header"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
      </Border>
      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <!-- snip -->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats how I tried it. But the problem is that on the subitems (the ones going into ItemsPresenter) then do have the expander-button on the right side too ...

Comment: Just set the template inside a datatrigger bound to the level property of your object

Comment: You mean I should switch the CONTROLtemplate inside a datatrigger?